Solve a trick differential partial equation
So basically I have came across a partial equation in the $AdS_{d+1}$ spacetime,
$$z_0^{d+1} (z_0^{-d+1} \phi_{,0})_{,0} + z_0^2 \phi_{,jj} = \delta^{d+1}(x-v)$$
Where $,k$ means derivative wrt $k$. Here, $\phi_{,jj} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_j^2}$, for example. And $j$ runs from $1$ to $d$
I am taking a really hard timeto solve it. When i see equations like this, my immediat approach is to use Fourier transform. So (the answer i am getting is wrong, so I will be a little loose about constant terms btw)
$$\phi(x_j,x_0) = \int e^{-ik_0 x_0 - k_i x_j} \tilde{\phi}(k,k_0) d^d k dk_0$$
Then
$$z_0^{d+1} (z_0^{-d+1} (-ik_0 \tilde{\phi}))_{,0} + z_0^2 (-i\vec{k})^2 \tilde{\phi} = 1$$
$$-ik_0 z_0^{d+1} ((1-d) z_0^{-d} \tilde{\phi} + z_0^{1-d} (-ik_0 \tilde{\phi})) + z_0^2 (-i\vec{k})^2 \tilde{\phi} = 1$$
$$-ik_0(1-d) z_0 \tilde{\phi} - k_0^2 z_0^{2} \tilde{\phi} - z_0^2 k^2 \tilde{\phi} = 1$$
$$\tilde{\phi} = \frac{-1}{ik_0(1-d) + k_0^2 z_0^2 + z_0^2 k^2}$$
And therefore
$$\phi(x_j,x_0) = \int e^{-ik_0 x_0 - k_i x_j}  \frac{-1}{ik_0(1-d) + z_0^2 (k_0^2 +  k^2)} d^d k dk_0$$
When i put this on Mathematica, it gives me a really weird answer, so i know it is wrong. How could i solve this diff equation?

Does the $\phi_{jj}$ term imply a sum over $j$ or that this equation is true for every $j$?

It is a summation, pratically the laplacian in flat spacetime @whpowell96

You can easily check if your weird answer satisfies the original pde

What is $z_0{}$?
